# xml.Unmarshall multi root XML in Go

Tags: xml, go

There is a API which I need to connect and fetch data from. There is no way to update API.

There are two type of responses, for errors:

```xml
<error>Database Error</error>
```

and for normal response:

```xml
<response>
  <device id="1">Test Device</device>
</response>
```

or like this:

```xml
<response>
  <user age="16">
    <username>TestUser</username>
    <role>user</role>
  </user>
</response>
```

What I try to implement, is to have one struct as `XmlResponse` so I can check if it has error first and then expected type as a member of the struct.

Below are datatypes which I implemented for API

```golang
type XmlResponse struct {
    Error  *XmlError
    Result *XmlResult
}

type XmlError struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"error"`
    Error   string   `xml:",innerxml"`
}

type XmlResult struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"response"`
    Device  *Device
    User    *User
}

type Device struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"device"`
    Id      int      `xml:"id,attr"`
    Label   string   `xml:",innerxml"`
}

type User struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"user"`
    Username string   `xml:"username"`
    Role     string   `xml:"role"`
    Age      int      `xml:"age,attr"`
}
```

But using `xml.Unmarshal` does not produce expected output. But if I wrap result with in some element and adjust `XmlResponse` struct as below:

```xml
<envelope>
  <error>Database Error</error>
</envelope>
```

and for normal response as:

```xml
<envelope>
  <response>
    <device id="1">Test Device</device>
  </response>
</envelope>
```

and struct as:

```golang
type XmlResponse struct {
    XMLName xml.Name   `xml:"envelope"`
    Error   *XmlError
    Result  *XmlResult
}
```

I can have expected result.

There is a sample code in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8ZOkdkXAYuC).

Is there a method so I can unmarshal xml into `XmlResponse` with different root element names without wrapping?

**UPDATE:** All response codes are 200, so I am not able differentiate between error and normal response by looking to response code.

Answer (score 0):

For catching errors returned by the API, you should usually check the response code and then act accordingly.
In your case, there should be a code >500 returned, indicating that there was a server-side error. Then you can try to unmarshal the response body according to the returned error-message-format.

If thats not an option, you could always try to unmarshal into the error-struct and if the operation fails with an error, you can catch it and unmarshal into your response-struct instead.

But you have to be careful on which error you catch as a failure to unmarshal into the error-type does not automatically mean that it is  a valid repsonse-type instead.

Comment: I have updated question, response code checking is not an option. Also trying to serialize first to error struct and then to response struct seems to me as waste of resources, IMHO better solution is to wrap response in some element and then unmarshaling works as in sample code in go playground in question.